# Load images onto page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, dom

Is there a way to load images into the dom after document is ready? In this example for instance, I wan't the image "photo" loaded onto the page when every other element has loaded:

```
<body>
  <div>
    <img id="photo" src="img/photo.jpg" alt="a furry little cat" />
    <p>Lorrem ipusum</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered adding the control dynamically to the DOM ?

Just give your div an id and access it using jQuery and supply the required HTML like so

```
$('#div').html('<img id="photo" src="img/photo.jpg" alt="a furry little cat" />');
```

You can do this inside `$(document).ready();` so that it loads after every other page element is loaded.

Comment: It looks like it did the trick, the paragraph dissapeared thoug, but thats actually great, I was planning on removing it when the document was ready too :)